# Store temp data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

For example, i have a class (User) and 30 values (properties), 10 of them i display in DataGridView as columns, but other (settings for each user (timeout to make requests for example, any other BL values)) about 20 values, i just want to store together in XML file (i could make Serialize/Deserialize).

So, i need to store anywhere this not displayed 20 values, what is the best practise for this?
Is it hidden column in DataGridView or anything else?

As i could understand, i have to store it together, but where i could do it? Should i make relationship between two block of stored data (User[10 values] + User[20 values]) to make them after that serialize in XML?

Comment: could put everything in a DataTable and not display it at all?

Comment: I don't have datatable. You advice me to create it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice as I have used frequently, is to retrieve all your data in a **collection** like `List, DataTable, EntityCollection, ...` or any `IEnumerable` Type and bind it to your `DataGridView` which has `AutoGenerateColumns = false`. In this case you should have **manually added the specific columns to the `DataGridView`** in designer or code. The code approach would be like this:

```
// say this is your User class with 9 fields
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
}
// and your Form1 class would be like this
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        // say you want to show, only the first 5 fields of your Entity
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Name", DataPropertyName = "Name", Width=100 });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Last Name", DataPropertyName = "LastName", Width = 100 });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Father's Name", DataPropertyName = "FatherName" });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Telephone", DataPropertyName = "Tel", Width = 50 });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Mobile", DataPropertyName = "Mobile", Width = 50 });
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<User> list = new List<User>();

        list.Add(new User { Name="aaa", LastName="bbbb", FatherName="ccc", Tel="01111", Mobile="099999" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it would be hard in future sync & work with List, as collection of data, when i have to change something, but thx

Comment: If user then want to change DataGridViewRow (for example, right click on row->edit) and i want to display him all values (even hidden) in dialog- how i get other values of this row? I need to make relationship in this case between List of values and rows in DataGridView

Comment: List in this example isn't obligatory! I know List binding is one-way, unlike DataTable. The point is how to show a subset of columns. You can use any other collection...

Comment: My biggest question, how i could take other values of entity from just GridViewRow (i think it's too bad make relate on index).

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[0].DataBoundItem as User`

Answer (score 0):

Usage of data caching will helpful to your scenerio.

Summary:

Data caching is storing data in memory for quick access. Typically information that is costly to obtain (in terms of performance) is stored in the cache. One of the more common items stored in a cache in a Web application environment is commonly displayed database values; by caching such information, rather than relying on repeated database calls, the demand on the Web server and database server's system resources are decreased and the Web application's scalability increased. As Microsoft eloquently puts it,

> "Caching is a technique widely used in computing to increase
>   performance by keeping frequently accessed or expensive data in
>   memory. In the context of a Web application, caching is used to retain
>   pages or data across HTTP requests and reuse them without the expense
>   of recreating them."

Please refer the link how to use data cache in asp.net

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-in-the-architecture-cs

http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2011/01/10/using-the-asp.net-cache-to-cache-data-in-a-model.aspx

http://blog.ntotten.com/2011/04/29/caching-data-in-asp-net-applications/

update:

If you don't have database and you are using winforms then store into list and make relationship using the linq query.

The following are links that would show how to use the joins and linqs

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/03/12/joins-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/05/28/linq-joins-and-groupings.aspx

Comment: Is it ok, if i don't use database and my project based on WinForms, as i tagged in question?

Comment: @user1612334: Sorry I haven't noticed that. Okay then you can go head storing into the data table or best way to store the values in form of list

Comment: @user1612334: To make relationship between two users, you can achieve through linq concept.

Comment: What is the "form of list" ?

Comment: Say you have class user . create the list like List<User> lstUser = new List<User>() ....  and then store all the values in the lists

Comment: Is this list should be static?